# Bootstrap typeahead error

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

please help me resolve this error with Bootstrap typeahead.

Here is my php code that I use to call for the source.

```
    function getUser() {

    $sth = mysql_query("SELECT id,contact FROM cinfo ORDER BY id ASC");
    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
}
```

Here is my javascript file

UPDATE 2 JS

```
        $('.user').typeahead({
    source : function(typeahead, query) {
        return $.post('/ticket/getUser', {
            query : query,
        }, function(data) {
            return typeahead.process(data);
        })
    },
    property : 'contact'
});
```

I get the following error is now produced https://gist.github.com/1866577#gistcomment-263183

I am using the following bootstrap typeahead script https://gist.github.com/1866577

Thank you.

Comment: Why you dont use mysql_fetch_array if you want to get the results into an array? And where is the `$i = 0;` for?

Answer (score 1):

You want to display `contact` not `cinfo`, because `cinfo` is the table name

```
$('.user').typeahead({
 source: '/ticket/getUser',
display:'contact',
id: 'id'
});
```

UPDATE:

Looks like you want to use the 'property' option:

```
$('.user').typeahead({
 source: '/ticket/getUser',
property:'contact'
});
```

UPDATE2:

I think you need to process the return data first. Try this:

```
$('.user').typeahead({
    source: function (typeahead, query) 
    {
        return $.post('/ticket/getUser', { query: query }, function (data) 
        {
            return typeahead.process(data);
        });
    },
    property:'contact'
});
```

Comment: It looks to me like your `getUser` function isn't returning the data in the correct format for this typeahead extension to work.  Try printing out the result from `getUser` into firebug using `console.log`

Comment: The following is returned with getUser [{"id":"1","contact":"a@abc.com"},{"id":"2","contact":"b@abc.com"},{"id":"3","contact":"c@abc.com"}]

Comment: Ok, I've had a read of the gist you linked, you might want to try using the `property` option instead

Comment: Ok so atleast I am getting something on typeahead now `<li class="active" data-value=""e"">
<li class="" data-value=""e"">
<li class="" data-value=""e"">
<li class="" data-value=""e"">
<li class="" data-value=""e"">
<li class="" data-value=""E"">` This is however not the full return data of contact

Comment: Hey @peacemaker I tried your second edit and I still get the return value as my edit mentions above. This is the exact same error I am getting btw https://gist.github.com/1866577#gistcomment-263183 I tried adding in the dataType as well.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the new code, including the added `dataType : 'json'` part

Comment: looks like a typo before the property option, needs a comma.  see my code

Comment: there was a bracket missing in your code which I added, still getting that previous error. When I visit the source link directly I see the normal json parse which I showed to you above.

Comment: have you tried just returning the data directly from the $.post call, instead of passing it through `typeahead.process` first??  i.e. `return $.post('/ticket/getUser', { query: query }, function (data) 
        {
            return data;
        })`

Comment: Yep I tried this, when I look into firebug I can see that request are being sent to the server and it also gets a response with the valid json data. Yet nothing shows up on the typeahead dropdown.

Comment: @peacemaker no I don't think it does.

Comment: @BaconJuice You don't need to return anything if you do process inside the success callback. Anyway you better use Terry solution.

Comment: @Sherbrow Terry's solution gives me the error stated below. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of tooting my own horn, if you're having trouble getting that Gist to work you can try my full typeahead extension which has the feature you're looking for and is supported with documentation and demos.

https://github.com/tcrosen/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead

Comment: Hey Terry your code also returns the following error on firebug `typeahead.lookup(): source object has no property named "contact"
`

Comment: That's a custom error message I put in, sounds like you've been using mine all along.  It means the JSON source doesn't have a "contact" property.

Comment: [This works](http://jsfiddle.net/BebVV/1/) so it sounds like your JSON isn't being sent into the plugin correctly.