# Bootstrap Typeahead only showing first letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a little issue getting this to work.

The server responses with the correct json request however typeahead only displays the first letter of my returned result. For example if I type k it will display:
k
k
K
k

Could you help me figure out why?

Here is my js

```
$('.user').typeahead({
source : function(typeahead, query) {
    return $.post('getUser', {
        query : query
    }, function(data) {
        return typeahead.process(data);
    });
}
});
```

and my html

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" size="16" id="appendedInputButton" class="user" data-provide="typeahead">
```

I'm using the following code

https://gist.github.com/1866577

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11346251/484072

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the server is responding with an array of objects with attribute 'contact', try this:

```
$('.user').typeahead({
  source : function(typeahead, query) {
      return $.post('getUser', {
          query : query
      }, function(data) {
          return typeahead.process(JSON.parse(data));
      });
  },
  property : 'contact'
});
```

Comment: I get the following error now return   ~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase())

Comment: What's a sample response from getUser?

Comment: The following is returned with getUser [{"id":"1","contact":"a@abc.com"},{"id":"2","contact":"b@abc.com"},{"id":"3","co‌​ntact":"c@abc.com"}]

Comment: Ok, if it's returning a list of objects you will need to specify the property. I''ve updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Been having this same problem myself today, discovered that I need to be sure and do

```
data-source="['THING1','THINGS2']"
```

Do **double quotes first**, then **single quotes inside**. I had this reversed initially and was only getting 1 letter. Also, make sure to not have a trailing **,** at the end of the array, as this will also cause just one letter to appear.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the class="user". It will start showing the whole thing.